# Are circular references between JSON Schemas (different files) allowed?

Tags: json, visual-studio-2013, circular-dependency, jsonschema

I have two JSON schemas that link each other:
**schema.task.json** and **schema.dependency.json**:

```
//file: schema.task.json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "Dependencies": { "type": "array", "items": { "$ref": "schema.dependency.json#" } },
        "TaskName": { "type": "string" }
    }
}

//file: schema.dependency.json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "StartAfterTask": { "$ref": "schema.task.json" },
        "DependencyName": {"type": "string"}
    }

}
```

When I try to edit json that use my Task schema, I see error in output window of visual studio:

> Error loading schema ...\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\schema.dependency.json
>
> > Value cannot be null. Parameter name: uriString

If I'm doing circular reference within one file (in definitions section), it works fine.

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, Update 5, with schema http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema

Does anyone know the right way to create JSON schemas with cross-files circular dependencies?

Comment: @RyanVincent - there are many questions about JSON Schema on StackOverflow, and a tag (`jsonschema`) for it.  This is an OK place to ask the question.

Comment: @cloudfeet, I didn't see Ryan's first post, but what's the BEST place to ask this question then?

Comment: @Philipp - The original comment was saying SO wasn't the best forum for this, and I think it's actually a pretty good one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is allowed - references between two different files are no different to reference within a file.

The syntax you've posted looks correct - have you tried raising an issue with the library you're using?

Comment: What do you mean by "library i'm using"? Visual Studio?

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise Visual Studio had support built-in!  Yes, if it's the built-editor that's having the issue, is there a way to raise an issue with that?

Comment: I also noticed that one of your references has a `#` and the other does not.  It *should* make absolutely zero difference, but as a long-shot: does adding/removing these change anything, as a workaround?